# vb.net SQL query to populate datagridview (over my head)

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Just wondering if anyone could help.

I first need to populate the datagridview with all the products from the sql table "sqlccmproduct" and then cross-reference "sqlinstructions" to see if it exists, and if it does populate the columns with "Yes" or "No" whether it is found or not, hopefully the picture attached can so it easier.

Many Thanks,
Pete

Code i have so far that populates the Datagridview with the products populated in the Board Column and labels the columns:

```
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT product FROM [sqlccmproduct] ORDER BY product ASC"

    Dim board_ranking_dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con.ConnectionString)
    Dim board_ranking_table As New DataTable()
    board_ranking_table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    board_ranking_dataAdapter.Fill(board_ranking_table)
    Me.BindingSource1.DataSource = board_ranking_table

    DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1

    disconnect()

    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Width = 140
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Width = 140
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).Width = 140
    DataGridView1.Columns(3).Width = 140
    DataGridView1.Columns(4).Width = 140
    DataGridView1.Columns(5).Width = 140
    DataGridView1.Columns(6).Width = 140
    DataGridView1.Columns(7).Width = 140

    DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Board:"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Prep:"
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Pre-Coat:"
    DataGridView1.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Pre-Oven:"
    DataGridView1.Columns(4).HeaderText = "After-Coat:"
    DataGridView1.Columns(5).HeaderText = "After-Oven:"
    DataGridView1.Columns(6).HeaderText = "Board Coverage:"
    DataGridView1.Columns(7).HeaderText = "Defect Coverage:"

    DataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False

    DataGridView1.Rows(0).Selected = True


    '' NOW CHECK EACH ROW

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If Not row.IsNewRow Then


        End If
    Next
```

EDIT: I've made it work for one row, but my "for each" row isnt working for some reason:

```
connect()

    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT product FROM [sqlccmproduct] ORDER BY product ASC"

    Dim board_ranking_dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con.ConnectionString)
    Dim board_ranking_table As New DataTable()
    board_ranking_table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    board_ranking_dataAdapter.Fill(board_ranking_table)
    Me.BindingSource1.DataSource = board_ranking_table

    DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1

    disconnect()

    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    DataGridView1.DataBindings.Clear()

    DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Board:"

    DataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False
    'DataGridView1.Rows(0).Selected = True

    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("prep", "Prep:")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("precoat", "Pre-Coat:")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("preoven", "Pre-Oven:")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("aftercoat", "After-Coat:")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("afteroven", "After-Oven:")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("boardcoverage", "Board Coverage:")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("defectcoverage", "Defect Coverage:")

    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Width = 140
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Width = 140
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).Width = 140
    DataGridView1.Columns(3).Width = 140
    DataGridView1.Columns(4).Width = 140
    DataGridView1.Columns(5).Width = 140
    DataGridView1.Columns(6).Width = 140
    DataGridView1.Columns(7).Width = 140

    '' NOW CHECK EACH ROW


    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        'If Not row.IsNewRow Then
        connect()

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) from [sqlinstructions] where pcb = '" & row.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "' and type = 'Prep'"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", row.Cells(0).Value.ToString)
        Dim count1 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        If count1 > 0 Then
            row.Cells(1).Value = "Yes"
            row.Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.Green
            row.Cells(1).Style.ForeColor = Color.White

        Else
            row.Cells(1).Value = "No"
            row.Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
            row.Cells(1).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        End If


        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) from [sqlinstructions] where pcb = '" & row.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "' and type = 'Pre-Coat'"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", row.Cells(0).Value.ToString)
        Dim count2 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        If count2 > 0 Then
            row.Cells(2).Value = "Yes"
            row.Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.Green
            row.Cells(2).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        Else
            row.Cells(2).Value = "No"
            row.Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
            row.Cells(2).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        End If


        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) from [sqlinstructions] where pcb = '" & row.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "' and type = 'Pre-Oven'"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", row.Cells(0).Value.ToString)
        Dim count3 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        If count3 > 0 Then
            row.Cells(3).Value = "Yes"
            row.Cells(3).Style.BackColor = Color.Green
            row.Cells(3).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        Else
            row.Cells(3).Value = "No"
            row.Cells(3).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
            row.Cells(3).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        End If


        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) from [sqlinstructions] where pcb = '" & row.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "' and type = 'After-Coat'"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", row.Cells(0).Value.ToString)
        Dim count4 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        If count4 > 0 Then
            row.Cells(4).Value = "Yes"
            row.Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.Green
            row.Cells(4).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        Else
            row.Cells(4).Value = "No"
            row.Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
            row.Cells(4).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        End If


        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) from [sqlinstructions] where pcb = '" & row.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "' and type = 'After-Oven'"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", row.Cells(0).Value.ToString)
        Dim count5 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        If count5 > 0 Then
            row.Cells(5).Value = "Yes"
            row.Cells(5).Style.BackColor = Color.Green
            row.Cells(5).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        Else
            row.Cells(5).Value = "No"
            row.Cells(5).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
            row.Cells(5).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        End If


        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) from [sqlinstructions] where pcb = '" & row.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "' and type = 'Board Coverage'"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", row.Cells(0).Value.ToString)
        Dim count6 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        If count6 > 0 Then
            row.Cells(6).Value = "Yes"
            row.Cells(6).Style.BackColor = Color.Green
            row.Cells(6).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        Else
            row.Cells(6).Value = "No"
            row.Cells(6).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
            row.Cells(6).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        End If


        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) from [sqlinstructions] where pcb = '" & row.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "' and type = 'Defect Coverage'"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", row.Cells(0).Value.ToString)
        Dim count7 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        If count7 > 0 Then
            row.Cells(7).Value = "Yes"
            row.Cells(7).Style.BackColor = Color.Green
            row.Cells(7).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        Else
            row.Cells(7).Value = "No"
            row.Cells(7).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
            row.Cells(7).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        End If
        disconnect()
        'End If
    Next
```

[image: What im trying to do]

Comment: Added to Post, thanks